# WTForms QuerySelectMultipleField Not sending List

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, wtforms

I am working on a Flask Application to do some event scheduling. I am having problems with WTForms QuerySelectMultipleField in my form.

forms.py

```
class EnterEvent(Form):
...
invitees = QuerySelectMultipleField('Invitees', query_factory=lambda:
                            models.User.query.order_by(models.User.name).all())
```

and in my **init**.py file where I parse the Form POST data. Just to test I tried to return request.form['invitees'] just to see what is passed. Eventually I want to validate the data and add it to my SQLite3 DB.

```
@app.route('/event', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def addEvent():
    form = EnterEvent()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        invitees = request.form['invitees']
        return invitees
```

the WTForm docs say that the QuerySelectMultipleField should return a list with ORM model instances but when I parse the POST request I am not getting a list.  I checked the POST data in my browser and it looks like when I select multiple objects it is sending more than one.

I can't seem to figure this out. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get your ORM model instances if you query your `form` object directly, rather then the 'raw' form data that's part of the request object

Assuming you're using Flask-WTF with it's little helpers built it, your `invitees` line should really read `invitees = form.invitees.data`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that you can get the ORM instances from the query form. I thought you can only parse the raw POST data. This is a huge help.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use that same method to get all the fields from the form instead of getting the 'raw' data like request.form['whatever']?

Comment: You would always use the `form.field_name.data` convention, otherwise you're not actually using the goodies of WTForms.  Ideally you should really be doing `if form.validate_on_submit():` instead of the `if request.method == 'POST'` because the former actually uses any wtf validation you have set up on the form data.