# wtforms-alchemy - what about pre-populating the form with relationship data?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

so...

This:

```
model_dictionary = model.as_dict() # some kind of dictionary
form = TheModelsForm(**model_dictionary) # https://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html
form.populate_obj(model)
return form
```

This let's me pre populate the model's form with fields from the model that are db.Columns.. Well.. what about db.relationships on the model?

The above code is not pre-populating the relationship fields; they show up but are left blank. Only the db.Column fields are pre-populated with values regardless of whether I force include the relationship values in the model_dictonary or not (for example,  model_dictionary['key_from_other_object'] = associated value).

Can this be accomplished? --Can't find anything on this..

**Edit:**
I solved my initial problem with:

```
form = TheModelsForm(obj=model)
form.populate_obj(model)
return form
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the events on the location's model to actually show up on the Location form...

```
class Event(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))

class Location(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    events = db.relationship('Event', backref=db.backref('events'))
```

I'm sure there is a logical reason why all the stuff I commented out isn't working.. I'm getting 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Event

    location_id = fields.SelectField(u'Location', coerce=int)


 class LocationForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = models.Location

        #events = fields.SelectField(u'Event', choices=[(g.id, g.selector) for g in models.Event.query.all()], coerce=int)

        # events = fields.SelectMultipleField('Event', 
        #     choices=[(g.id, g.selector) for g in models.Event.query.all()],
        #     coerce=int,
        #     option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
        #     widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
        #     )

        #events = ModelFieldList(fields.FormField(EventForm))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

was barking up the wrong tree using SelectMultipleField and SelectField..

Instead,

`wtforms_alchemy.fields.QuerySelectMultipleField` @ https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/wtforms-alchemy/latest/wtforms-alchemy.pdf

and

this post, which helped to show usage, @ [WTForms QuerySelectMultipleField Not sending List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499369/wtforms-queryselectmultiplefield-not-sending-list)

solved my problem..

..ended up with

```
class LocationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Location

    events = wtforms_alchemy.fields.QuerySelectMultipleField('Event', 
        query_factory=lambda: models.Event.query.order_by(models.Event.name).all(), 
        get_label= lambda x: x.name,
        option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
        widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
        )
```